# Cannot Pull Oil Dipstick

Tags: ford, oil

Here's a simple, yet frustrating, problem.  I cannot check my oil, because the dipstick is stuck fast to the tube.

I don't really want to pull and twist so hard that it breaks off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pulling it when the engine is hot. A that point the metals might have expanded a little and you might actually get it out.

Comment: I agree - you might want to add a couple of firm taps with a metal mallet as well.  Don't bend anything - you just want to let any corrosion or adhesion know that you mean business.